# Как в Firefox убрать рамку для элементов таблицы в фокусе?

Tags: firefox, css

Firefox разрешает брать элементы таблицы в фокус при зажатой клавише Ctrl. При этом элементы, которые находятся в фокусе, подсвечены синий рамкой. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как её убрать? Вариант с `outline: none` не работает.

Comment: Сержо спасибо помогло, но не совсем так как хотелось. Если задать таблицу свойство -moz-user-select: none или -moz-none то работать будет, но в этом случае нельзя выделить текст, в идеале должно было подойти свойство text, но оно возврашает всё как и было... Хотя это наверное происходит не фокус, а просто выделение элемента таблицы так как событие onfocus он не вызывает...

Comment: *::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
Ваше лекарство не помогло! Я не понимаю кто такие ответы плюсует...

Comment: вот сами посмотрите http://jsfiddle.net/A4fkX/

Comment: Доктор я может быть и нормальный, но вот диагностикой занимаюсь слабовато, потому лекарство и не работает. Сейчас обновлю ответ. А вы старайтесь комментарии писать к ответам, а не к своему вопросу, иначе они могут остаться незамеченными.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Css.Как убрать пунктирную рамку вокруг button'а?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610727/css-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-button%d0%b0)

Comment: @Vadizar очевидно, что этот вопрос задан раньше и что в ответах то же самое. Зачем вы отмечаете его дубликатом к новому вопросу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPD:
Это дейсвительно фича firefox. Так он показывает выделенные узлы (не текстовые). Если вы желаете оставить возможность выделение текстовых узлов, то без js тут не обойтись. Я обновил [ваш фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/A4fkX/2/), добавил простой скрипт для firefox (не тестировал на старых версиях!). Надеюсь, суть ясна и у вас получится адаптировать скрипт под свою реализацию.

---

OLD:
Лекарство такое:

```
*::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: извиняюсь, буду добавлять комментарии не к своим постам. Решение не совсем то, но подходит, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйту `-moz-user-select`.

Возможно это просто фича ФФ и она не убирается.

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема может возникнуть и на input'ах. При этом, блоки могут иметь еще и лишний отступ. Поэтому надежнее будет написать так:

```
// Remove border and padding in Firefox
::-moz-focus-outer, ::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```