# Как убрать рамку вокруг button, input и некоторых других элементов в Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

Применяю такой способ:

```
* {
  outline: 0 !important;
}
```

В Chrome все работает, а вот Firefox наотрез отказывается принимать этот код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная проблема может возникнуть и на input'ах. При этом, блоки могут иметь еще и лишний отступ. Поэтому надежнее будет написать так:

```
// Remove border and padding in Firefox
::-moz-focus-outer, ::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: А padding зачем?

Comment: @Yuri я все расписал.

Answer (score 8):

вот так

```
button::-moz-focus-inner 
{
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало